# How to identify JQuery version being used in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i found  this page:
https://crossme.jp/

and I wonder if it's using fullpage javascript for the images. I know that is using three JavaScript for the effect of the cursor, but for the effect of background images I don't know.

I use google inspect for all my projects and I don't how to debug the java-scripts in the page.

Please help as I want to replicate this page.

Comment: Have you reviewed `Sources` tab?

Comment: In the console, $.fn.jquery shows the jQuery version.

Answer (score 1):

1. In chrome you can check source tab in developer tools and find it out.
2. Or you can simply check the page source of the webpage and search for jquery.

But to answer your question, this page is using **jQuery v1.10.2**

And for the cursor as well as 3D effects for images, this page is using mrdoob's 3D library : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Comment: How do you identify the version in the source files, if jquery is bundled in a bigger file (i.e. when all scripts are concatenated into a single bundle) or if the filename simply has no version number?

Comment: Ah seems like too late to revert but I guess the check jQuery().jquery still works. Please try and let me know.